# R replace string with character after a sequence

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to replace a string with the character comma `,`, only if the string appears right **after a digit**.

Here is an example -

```
text1 = "PaulWilliamsnéle110187auCaire"
text2 = "StaceyMauranéele190991auMaroc"
```

When I try using the `str_replace_all` function from `stringr`, it replaces all instances of 'au' from the texts.

```
str_replace_all(text1,"au",",")
str_replace_all(text2,"au",",")
```

The above functions give the following outputs

> P,lWilliamsnéle110187,Caire

> StaceyM,ranéele190991,Maroc

However, I'd only like the `"au"` to be removed following the final digit in the texts, not before.

So ideally, the desired output would be -

> PaulWilliamsnéle110187,Caire

> StaceyMauranéele190991,Maroc

But I'm unable to figure out how to put this condition into the function, so it only removes the `"au"` following the final digits for both texts.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
 string <- c(text1, text2)
 sub("(.*\\d+)(au)(.*)", "\\1,\\3", string)
[1] "PaulWilliamsnéle110187,Caire" "StaceyMauranéele190991,Maroc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a look behind. ie `(?<=\\d)au` where we check for `au` that is preceeded by a digit:

```
sub("(?<=\\d)au", ",", string, perl = TRUE)
[1] "PaulWilliamsnéle110187,Caire" "StaceyMauranéele190991,Maroc"
```

You could also match the digit and au `(\\d)au` and capture the digit then replace the whole matched part with the captured group and a comma

```
sub("(\\d)au", "\\1,", string)
[1] "PaulWilliamsnéle110187,Caire" "StaceyMauranéele190991,Maroc"
```